# Magic mouse multi touch feature wont work

Tags: mouse, macbook, scrolling

I just got a new magic mouse and the left and right click work fine but the swiping and scrolling wont work. I am running Snow Leopard (Version 10.6) on my 2009 MacBook and have performed all the updates. I have tried disconnecting and restarting the mouse and computer in all the combinations I can think of but still nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Have you enabled swiping and scrolling in System Preferences?

Comment: For some reason that preference doesn't show up when I open the preferences for the mouse. The only things it shows are the tracking speed, double click speed, and primary mouse button.

Comment: Did you install the drivers?

Answer (score 1):

Ok problem solved. As it turns out I had to go to http://support.apple.com/downloads/ and go back and find all the Snow Leopard OSX updates and download versions 10.6.1 - 10.6.3. If you are having the same problem I was having you should know that just going to the apple symbol and then to Software Updates is not enough to update your system to support all the magic mouse functions.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem because of a conflict with USB Overdrive. I thought it was uninstalled, but apparently I hadn't removed the kernel extension at */System/Library/Extensions/USBOverdrive.kext*. Running the uninstaller fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I have an iMac with OSX 10.6.8. My problem was that the computer was recognizing the mouse as a Mighty Mouse and not a Magic Mouse and would not allow the scroll and swipe capabilities.

What I did to fix it was **use the remote mouse app on my iPhone to control the computer** while I disconnected and rediscovered the mouse and for some reason, after that, it is recognized as a Magic Mouse and has all of the necessary capabilities.

I assume this would work if a USB mouse was connected to accomplish the same fix.